# issue in while render the views using html in ruby on rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

In my project, on click of check box, am calling getProducts method using ajax. It gets all product details, but am getting errors.

In my application.js am doing like this:

```
function getProducts(siteid)
{
    if(document.getElementById("cb_site"+siteid).checked==true)
    {
        var theURL = '/index_s/' + siteid;
            $.ajax({
                url: theURL
            });
    }
}
```

If i try to fetch the product details (controller) like

```
@products=ProductDetail.where("site_id=?",params[:siteid])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html redirect_to @products.home
  format.js
end
```

Am getting error

**NoMethodError (undefined method `home' for #)**

if i tried like this (product details controller)

```
@products=ProductDetail.find_by_site_id(params[:siteid])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html redirect_to @products.home
  format.js
end
```

am getting error like this:

**NoMethodError (undefined method `home' for #)**

if i tried like this (product_details controller)

```
@products=ProductDetail.all
respond_to do |format|
  format.html redirect_to @products.home
  format.js
end
```

am getting error

**undefined method `home' for #<Array:0xb075138>**

and i have views like home.html.erb

```
<div id="product_details">
    <%= render 'index' %>
</div>
```

In _index.html.erb
am displaying the products

In index.js.erb

```
$('#product_details').html('<%= escape_javascript render ('index') %>');
```

In router.rb

```
  match "index_s/:siteid" => 'product_details#index'
```

Please help me to come to from this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller am doing the mistake. I changed my controller code as show below and my problem is solved

In app/controller/product_details

```
def index
    @products=ProductDetail.where("site_id=?",params[:siteid])
end
```

app/views/product_details/home.html.erb

```
<div id="product_details">
    <%= render 'index' %>
</div>
```

In app/views/product_details/_index.html.erb

display product details

In index.js.erb

```
$('#product_details').html('<%= escape_javascript render ('index') %>');
```